# C++ exceptions and the .eh_frame ELF section

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, elf

Is it that the absence or damage of the .eh_frame ELF section is the cause of exceptions in my C++ code stopped working? Any exception that previously was caught successfully is now calling std::terminate().

My situation:

1. My zzz.so shared library has try-catch blocks:

   ```
   try {
       throw Exc();
   } catch (const Exc &e) {
       LOG("ok " << e.what());
   } catch (...) {
       LOG("all");
   }
   ```
2. An executable which loads the zzz.so (using ldopen). It call a function in the zzz.so
3. All the exceptions thrown in the zzz.so are successfully caught inside zzz.so and dumped into my log file
4. There is another aaa.so that is loaded into another binary. That another aaa.so is loading my zzz.so.
5. All the same exceptions thrown in the zzz.so lead to call std::terminate().

How is that possible?

**update**

I don't know HOW is that possible still, but Clang 3.3 (FreeBSD clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final 183502) 20130610) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is that possible?

When an exception is thrown, control passes to `__cxa_throw` routine (usually in `libstdc++.so`), which is then responsible for finding the `catch` clause and calling destructors along the way, *or* calling `std::terminate` if no `catch` is found.

The answer then is most likely that the first executable (the one where exceptions work) uses `libstdc++.so` that is capable of decoding `.eh_frame` in your library, while the second application (the one where exceptions do not work), either uses an older (incompatible) version of `libstdc++.so`, or links against `libstdc++.a`, or something along these lines.

Note: the *actual* work of raising the exception is done by `_Unwind_RaiseException` in `libgcc_s.so.1`, so even if both applications use the same `libstdc++.so`, they may still use different `libgcc`.

**Update:**

> Will I benefit from static linking libstdc++ and libgcc into my .so library?

Maybe. TL;DR: it's complicated.

There are a few things to consider:

1. On any platform other than i386, you would have to build your own copy of `libstdc++.a` and `libgcc.a` with `-fPIC` before you can link them into your `zzz.so`. Normally these libraries are built without `-fPIC`, and can't be statically linked into any `.so`.
2. Static linking of `libstdc++.a` into your `zzz.so` *may* make it a derived work, and subject to GPL (consult your lawyer).
3. Even when there is a `_Unwind_RaiseException` exported from `zzz.so`, normally there will already be another instance of `_Unwind_RaiseException` defined in (loaded earlier) `libgcc_s.so`, and that earlier instance is the one that will be called, rendering your workaround ineffective. To make sure that *your* copy of `_Unwind_RaiseException` is called, you would need to link `zzz.so` with `-Bsymbolic`, or with a special linker script to make all calls to `_Unwind_RaiseException` (and everything else from `libgcc.a`)  internal.
4. Your workaround may fix the problem for `zzz.so`, but may cause a problem for unrelated `yyy.so` that is loaded even later, and that wants the system-provided `_Unwind_RaiseException`, not the one from `zzz.so`. This is another argument for hiding all  `libgcc.a` symbols and making them internal to `zzz.so`.

So the short answer is: such workaround is somewhat likely to cause you a lot of pain.

Comment: Will I benefit from static linking libstdc++ and libgcc into my .so library?

Comment: Is "__cxa_throw" just a wrapper for "_Unwind_RaiseException" ?

Comment: @pavelkolodin Yes, for some definition of "just a wrapper". It doesn't merely call `_Unwind_RaiseException` if that's what you mean. It's source is here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_throw.cc#L60

Comment: My .so exceptions stop working if I add -std=c++11 to compiler g++47. But ldd's output for both versions of the final .so is THE SAME. Without -std=c++11 everything works fine.

Comment: I also noticed that -std=c++11 .so binary has no section ".tdata" which appears if I remove -std=c++11 compiler option.