# How the GNU linker treat .eh_frame ELF section?

Tags: c++, exception, ld, elf

1. Can `.eh_frame` or `.eh_frame_hdr` section of a **.so** shared library be overwritten by `.eh_frame` of another **.so** while loading a sequence of **.so** files for an executable while resolving sumbols?
2. Does `.eh_frame` consider relocation issues? Is it guaranteed that `.eh_frame` of a **.so** library will provide C++ `try-catch` correct work (exceptions doesn't cross "**.so** boundaries") for any binary using the code from the **.so** library? For example, the code in **.so** throws and catches all its exceptions (internally) then successfully writes error messages to a log file when called from binary **A** (that uses my **.so** library). Could linking process for some another binary **B** hurt the "exception mechanics" and how could that happen exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is no, and your second question appears to be *exact* duplicate of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33035051/50617).