# C++ exceptions inside DLL (MinGW)

Tags: c++, windows, exception, dll, mingw

I am making a Windows DLL in C++, MinGw 4.8. The library internally uses C++ classes and exceptions, but its interface is C-only, ie. no exception is propagated outside the library.

Unfortunately when I compile the library with `-static` option, the C++ exceptions are not caught. Even this simple example fails, the exception is not caught and the application is aborted:

```
try {
    throw std::logic_error("Hello World");
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Exception caught" << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile the library without `-static` command line switch, it works fine. The funny thing is that the older versions of my library used to work even with static linking and now I am quite confused why it stopped working...

I am calling the library from a simple testing C++ application compiled by the same compiler, but I need to make the library compatible also with other compilers/languages.

Please does anybody have a suggestion how to fix this problem?

**EDIT:** I tried to replace the `-static` option by `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc` options. Now when I remove `-static-libgcc`, exception handling works properly.

So my problem is related to static linking of libgcc, but I still cannot figure out why this matters. Any ideas?

**EDIT2:** When I debug my DLL, it calls `_Unwind_RaiseException` function embedded in the DLL. It looks like some kind of ABI incompatibility... Here the people deal with similar issue:
[C++ exceptions and the .eh_frame ELF section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035051/c-exceptions-and-the-eh-frame-elf-section)

Klasyc

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15670258/2135548) you can try avoiding SJLJ exception implementation